# Xamarin iOS - SignalR stops receiving messages in background mode

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, signalr, background-task

Currently i am developing an app which needs to be capable of receiving and interacting based on realtime event notifications from all platforms. We are using SignalR to achieve so. I am using Xamarin.Forms as this is a shared project.

Right now everything is working fine especially android is perfect. No matter application is in background or foreground its receiving messages from SignalR and playing sound and vibrates as expected. In iOS 10.3 simulator also its working as expected. Untill yesterday when i realized in real device when application goes in background mode it pauses everything and when its back in foreground it resumes as its supposed to be doing and as if the notification was sent just now. So i did some research and thought i would perform a long running task (in my case a forever loop with a 10seconds interval) in the background thread and in that way i was able to receive signalr messages (which i can see on the debugger) and vibration was playing while being in background. But after a certain time i am guessing within 10 mins iOS is clearing up its memory and when i open the app it seems reloaded because it shows the login screen instead of where i left the app.

Now question is:
1. How can i keep receiving SignalR events while being in background?
2. How can i stop iOS to reload my app due to being in background for a long time?
3. The app has to be Appstore publishable as in appstore must not reject it due to some dodgy works being done in the background like playing silent audio forever or using VoIP for background since this is not a VoIP app.
4. Also soon i am gonna be implementing location update in background mode so is this gonna keep the whole app alive in background? And behave like i am expecting?

As i am currently travelling i can not provide any code snippet but any questions please feel free to ask.

Thanks for your help and reading this boring article.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle/preparing_your_app_to_run_in_the_background/updating_your_app_with_background_app_refresh

Comment: you mean to say SIgnalR works in your android application when in background?

Comment: Yes it is. When I wrote that app I tested on devices running upto android 7. Its now 8.1 and still working fine. In android the only problem is you cannot or i couldnt exclude my app from battery optimisation programmatically and of course with permission. But you can do that manually from your battery setting. Another key is you need to collect location data continuously regardless of your app state (you have to have a valid reason to be able to do that if you want to publish your app in the market). This will keep signalr and your app alive in the background.

Comment: Btw there are definitely ways to exclude app from battery optimisation i just couldnt do it

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if someone is facing similar issue.
Apple doesnt allow to execute your app unless it falls in certain category [Look at table 3-1](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html). Fortunately, I had a valid reason to use continuous location update in foreground and background therefore as soon as I implemented location update event all my problems were solved immediately.

How to implement location update? [Location DependencyService example for Xamarin.Forms](http://www.codemag.com/Article/1707071/Accessing-Platform-Specific-Functionalities-Using-DependencyService-in-Xamarin.Forms)
Hope that will help.